# OpenOPC Gateway Running use Client in OsX or Linux

Tags: python, opc

I use the `OpenOPC` library for `python` https://sourceforge.net/projects/openopc/
in gateway mode... Gateway runs on Windows and the client should run on `Linux`.

This usecase is also forseen by the Library in its documetation.

But... The library uses the `pythoncom` library in `pyhton` which is a Windows package.. how do I get around that since i cant install `Pywin32` in `macosx`?

the Error Message:

```
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
NameError: global name 'pythoncom' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed... It was just a programming mistake:

I ran:

```
 opc.client('ipaddress')
```

but in to use the gateway service it has to be:

```
opc.open_client('ipaddress')
```

Comment: I developed a OPC Rest API on top of OpenOPC as I also had issues with connecting from Linux and App environments. Code on https://github.com/matzpersson/opc-rest-api