# converting OPC DA to REST API

Tags: rest, opc

How do I  convert OPC DA protocol in to Rest API calls? I was looking at the OpenOPC library https://github.com/mkwiatkowski/openopc. Will I have to write the Rest API part of the architecture myself? Are there libraries that already have this conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the library https://github.com/matzpersson/opc-rest-api
From the description of the project:

> Python Rest API using OpenOPC to provide direct API access for any OS
> platform. This proxy has to be installed on a Windows box with Python
> and OpenOPC installed to provide a API Gateway to other platforms.

The description is here http://headstation.com/archives/using-opc-rest-api/
From that it looks like you don't need to write the Rest API part yourself.

The library has been created by https://stackoverflow.com/users/6833456/matz see question [OpenOPC Gateway Running use Client in OsX or Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334505/openopc-gateway-running-use-client-in-osx-or-linux)

Comment: This looks like exactly what I was looking for. I will  examine the library.Install it and check to see if it works and mark this as an answer!